# "Moral fibre of celebrities" Should I treat this as a collective noun?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

> The Moral fibre of celebrities **is \ are** questionable.

I guess "The Moral fibre of celebrities" is a collective noun and should be treated as singular and, therefore, The Moral fibre of celebrities is questionable.

Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely the case that *moral fibre* is treated as a mass noun. It seems odd to me that you'd say something like this:

> ？ I don't approve of either of her moral fibres.

While *fibres* is countable, and we actually say *he had good morals*, we don't say *he had only two good morals*. In other words, the plural form of both  *morals* and *fibres* is possible—but *morals* isn't used in an actually countable sense, nor would be the compound term *moral fibres*.

So, the question is do both of the following make sense?

> ✔ The moral fibre of celebrities is questionable.
>   ？ The moral fibres of celebrities are questionable.

The singular version is undoubtedly correct. And if choosing between *is* and *are* as the word to follow *the moral fibre of celebrities*, it's irrelevant if *moral fibre* is a mass noun or not, because subject-verb agreement has *is* being used anyway.

From a purely syntactical point of view, the second sentence with *are* is the only version that could be used if the sentence starts with *the moral fibres*, but my inclination is to say that *moral fibre* is a mass noun and it would not be used in such a construction.